# ios 11 : UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage get nil value

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios11

I have open Image gallery by using below code

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerView = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
pickerView.allowsEditing=true;
[self presentViewController:pickerView animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

I have also set delegate  in UIViewController.

But I am getting nil value for **UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage** 
in `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info;`

I have also printed the value of the info and getting below result.

Printing description of info:

```
{
    UIImagePickerControllerCropRect = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {2999.999927356841, 2006.2499514198873}}";
    UIImagePickerControllerImageURL = "file:///Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/..../A33241F6-6CAB-4B0E-8B21-3D81797A4079.jpeg";
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x6040002bb2a0> size {3000, 2002} orientation 0 scale 1.000000";
    UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED&ext=JPG";
}
```

Here you can see iOS not giving UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage value.

**Is this iOS 11 Bug or how I can get the edited image object?**

Comment: Was the image actually edited as part of the image selection action by the user?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @iDev any solution?